# do something when modal hides

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm facing an issue with a modal, I have one and when I close it I need running something, actually when it closes, I need refresh the index.php.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery.min_2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap3.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />

    <script>

    $('#myModal').modal({
      'show': false
    });


    $('#btnModal').click(function() {

      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });

    $('#myModal').on('hide', function(e) {
      if (!confirm('You want to close me?'))
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    </script>   

    </head>
<body><!-- Button trigger modal -->

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<a role="button" class="btn" id="btnModal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have this example, and I can't do it works. Someone could help me? Thks

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap have it's own shown & hidden event names:

`on('shown.bs.modal',function() { ... })`

`on('hidden.bs.modal',function() { ... })`

Hope this help.
Good luck!

**UPDATE:** More bootstrap's modal event names:

`show.bs.modal`     : Occurs when the modal is about to be shown
`shown.bs.modal`    : Occurs when the modal is fully shown (after CSS transitions have completed)
`hide.bs.modal`     : Occurs when the modal is about to be hidden
`hidden.bs.modal` : Occurs when the modal is fully hidden (after CSS transitions have completed)

See the Bootstrap docs for further reference: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events